# Checking for the existence of a column in a view before searching for a value

Tags: sql, view, plsql

I am trying to search every view in the database for a specific value of something like '%THIS%'

I came up with this plsql code

```
DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT name FROM user_dependencies where type = 'VIEW') LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '|| t.name || ' Where Column_Name LIKE ''%THIS%'' '
    INTO match_count;

    IF match_count > 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( t.name ||' '||match_count );
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

But when I try to run it, I get an invalid identifier error for the column name in the execute immeadiate query.

The problem to me is obvious that not every view has the Column_Name, but I can't figure out how I can check to see if the column exists before running the query as I loop through all of the views.

I was also able to use a slightly modified version of this to run through all of the tables, and while they do not all have that column, I did not run in to this issue.

Edit: I am including the plsql code that I was able to use to loop through the tables.

```
DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_columns 
            where table_name LIKE 'THIS%' and data_type = 'VARCHAR2' AND column_name = 'Column_name') LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||t.table_name || ' Where Column_name LIKE ''%THIS%'' '
    INTO match_count;

    IF match_count > 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( t.table_name ||' '||t.column_name||' '||match_count );
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this is Oracle since you tagged pl/sql. You can use Oracle's metadata tables to see what columns a table/view has.  Specifically [USER_TAB_COLUMNS](http://ss64.com/orad/USER_TAB_COLUMNS.html).

```
select count(*) 
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name = [name of view] 
and column_name = [name of column]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I do know how to query individual views/tables on what columns they have. My problem is that I don't know how to check if a particular column exists while looping through all of them. There are too many views to do this individually and as far as I am aware there is no if(column_name.exists){} functionality. I included the code I used to loop through the tables in an edit.

Comment: @user1399217 I'm failing to see where the issue is.  `all_tab_columns` returns both tables and views

Answer (score 0):

This should query every view that has a column_name like '%START%'

```
declare
cursor getViews is
select table_name, column_name from user_tab_cols where table_name in
(select view_name from user_views)
and column_name like '%START%';
myResult number;
BEGIN
   for i in getViews
   LOOP
      execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||i.table_name into myResult;
   END LOOP;
END;
```